# Paragraph title as an headline, rather than a start for the text itself

Tags: paragraphs

So I can not switch to another package that would allow me to use fun stuff like \subsubsubseciton or stuff like that because then I would have to change my whole structure. My question is simply how can I use the paragraph titles as headlines, so that after they appear there is an instant line break afterwards without using these ugly dots? Thanks in advance!

```
 \subsection{Buch Seite 49}
    \subsubsection{Nr. 8}
        \paragraph{d)} .\\
        $f(x)= -x^2+6x+7$
        \paragraph{e)} .\\
        $f(x)= x^3-3x^2-x+3$
    \subsection{Nr. 10}
        \paragraph{a)} .\\

        \paragraph{c)} .\\

 \subsection{Buch Seite 50}
    \subsubsection{Nr.11}
        \paragraph{b)} .\\

    \subsubsection{Nr.14}
        \paragraph{a)} .\\
```

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine the format for `paragraph`s using the `titlesec` package to get the style you want.

For example like:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\paragraph}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
```